# Why need we assign the grad of y in Chainer?

Tags: chainer

I am a novice of Chainer. I am doing by the Guides. However, I find something that I think it is strange.
In the Docs » Guides » Variable Chapter, I write the blow code:

```
x = Variable(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float32))
y = 2.0 * x
# y.grad = np.zeros((2, 3), dtype=np.float32)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
print(y.data)
```

Then, there is a error, the error message is :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

And when we delete the annotated sign, the code is :

```
x = Variable(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float32))
y = 2.0 * x
y.grad = np.zeros((2, 3), dtype=np.float32)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
print(y.data)
```

Then everything is ok.

So it seems that it must to assign the initial grad to the variable of y. I think this is strange. Should it be one as a default value?

I am looking for your explanation for that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

When the output `y` is not a scalar, Chainer does not fill the initial gradient automatically because backpropagation, in this case, computes Jacobian-vector product for which the vector (given by the output grad) is needed. `ones` is just an example of the vector which is not special, thus Chainer forces the user to explicitly specify it.

When the output is a scalar (array with shape `()`), Chainer automatically fills the output by one (see [the reference](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.Variable.html#chainer.Variable.backward)). It means backpropagation computes the gradient of a scalar-valued function by default, which is natural.

Comment: But, when I execute the code y = x**2 + 2.0 * x, even if I annotated the sentence of assign grad , it also can be executed. in this case, the y is not a scalar too. How can we explanation for that?